# Issues creating table plot of column pandas DataFrame data?

Tags: python, pandas, tabular

I have the following code which creates a table image with the column names labelled. The issue I am having is getting the columns (dc[x]) to be able to populate the table vertically as opposed to horizontally.

```
def drilltable():
    c = readcsv3()
    dc = DataFrame(c)
    topA,ARA,PWA, = dc[0],dc[1],dc[2],
    data=[topA,ARA,PWA]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,axisbg='white')
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_aspect(.2)
    cols=["Top Drillers in Alberta", "Active Rigs", "Prev Week"]
    table = ax.table(cellText=data, colLabels=cols, loc='upper center',cellLoc='center',colWidths=[.075]*18)
    for cidx in table._cells:
        table._cells[cidx].set_facecolor('#EEECE1')
    table.set_fontsize(20)
    table.scale(2.1,16)

    plt.savefig(filenameTemplate3, format='png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

The below image is what I am currently getting, which has the correct column labels but the values are listed horizontally instead of below each col label.

[image]

Instead, I would like something that looks more like this (did in excel, because I cant get it to work in python):

[image]

The issue is that in the when I set the ax.table() function, cellText=data assigns the cells horizontally, I would like it vertically as the data is in that format.

Any suggestions?

Here is an example of data I am trying to read into the table (actual file is 11x12), via CSV file.

```
Top Dillers AB      Active Rigs       Prev. Week
Tourmaline Oil Corp    10                 9
CNRL                   8                  8
Seven Generations      7                  10
Encana Corp            6                   7
Peyto Exploration      5                   6
```

Comment: I suggest you to write a short, self-contained, correct example, where one can identify the pb quickly.

Comment: There I tried to make it a bit more clear in what I am looking to get.

Comment: But create fake data so I can try